# Database Login Failed: Crystal Reports

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, crm, crystal-reports-2008

Encountered issues when deploying a Crystal Report on Ungerboeck whereby I would get a 'Database Login Failed' when I tried to run the report.

Was deploying to a hosted CRM (Ungerboeck) using SQL Server Native Client 11

Answer (score 0):

When creating a Crystal Report that connects to a Database stored off-site or locally you will need to specify the Database Type and Provider.

I've discovered it can occur because you have selected the incorrect Provider.

For SQL Server it is best to use OLE DB (ADO) for your database type, and Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server rather than any other provider.